# Make apache avro schema of a simple API

Tags: data-modeling, avro

I want to make schema of a simple API in Apache Avro, but issue is that my API has header field "Content-Type", and Avro disallows "-" in name.
Here is my JSON:

```
"headers": {"Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"}
```

Here is schema sample:

```
{
  "name": "headers",
  "type": {
    "type": "record",
    "name": "headers",
    "fields": [
      { "name": "Content-type", "type": ["string", "null"] }
    ]
  }
},
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Represent the headers using an Avro [map](https://avro.apache.org/docs/1.8.2/spec.html#Maps) instead of record:

```
{
  "name": "headers",
  "type": {
    "type": "map",
    "values": "string"
  }
},
```